# Terminal command escaping issue

Tags: python, escaping

I am trying to escape the following, so I can grab the version of iDevice attached via USB:

`system_profiler SPUSBDataType | sed -n -e 's/  */ /g' -e '/iPad/,/Version/p' -e '/iPhone/,/Version/p' | grep 'iPad\|iPhone\|Version' | awk 'NR%2{printf $0;next;}1'`

So I can run it via Popen, however everytime I always get an issue on `iPad\|iPhone\|Version`, my code is the following, in an attempt to escape the single quotes:

```
cmd1 = Popen([r'system_profiler', 'SPUSBDataType'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
cmd2 = Popen([r'sed','-n','-e','\'s/  */ /g\'','-e','\'/iPad/,/Version/p\'', '-e', '\'/iPhone/,/Version/p\''], stdin=cmd1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
cmd3 = Popen([r'grep', '\'iPad\|iPhone\|Version\''], stdin=cmd2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
cmd4 = Popen([r'awk', '\'NR%2{printf $0;next;}1\''], stdin=cmd3.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
cmd1.stdout.close() 
ver = cmd4.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Why not do the replacing, grepping and data selection in Python itself? You don't really need `sed`, `grep` or `awk` here, do you?

Comment: Is there an easy way to do all that without loads of lines of code? The output of `system_profiler` is massive, `system_profiler SPUSBDataType | awk 'NR%2{printf $0;next;}1'` is manageable but still 20-30ish lines

Comment: Just loop over the `stdout` pipe of `cmd1` and read line by line?

Answer (score 1):

Use a raw string literal, or double the backslashes; `\|` has a meaning in a Python string definition syntax *too*, resulting in no backslash being present in the resulting value. You don't need those quotes either (the shell would have removed them too):

```
cmd3 = Popen([r'grep', r"iPad\|iPhone\|Version"], stdin=cmd2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

It'd be much easier to apply the string filtering and replacements in Python code, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I played around with grep tho and got to where I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Played around with grep and managed to extract what I needed from system_profiler. However Martijn's answer is more suitable if you cannot grep for the necessary string.

```
 prof = Popen(['system_profiler', 'SPUSBDataType'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 grep1 = Popen(['grep','-e','iPhone','-e','iPad','-e','iPod', '-A', '4'], stdin=prof.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 grep2 = Popen(['grep', 'Version'], stdin=grep1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 prof.stdout.close()  # Allow ps_process to receive a SIGPIPE if grep_process exits.
 stdoutver = grep2.communicate()[0]
```